# Is there (or is there planned to be) a method of performing manual scaling on a streaming Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

If you are running a streaming pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow, is there (or is there planned to be at some point in the future) a method of manually scaling the number of requested worker instances up and down based on some form of custom metric or API call? Or does such scaling require performing a clean shutdown of the pipeline, a difficult task in and of itself even in the most well-controlled circumstances, and then restarting it completely with a different number of instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there isn't a way of scaling the number of workers for a running pipeline. We are aware of this need and are working on several avenuse for addressing it. Stay tuned!